# Reinstalling Ubuntu made it unbootable

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, 17.10

Yesterday I decided to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 and to use a bootable USB drive to do that. The plan was to assign partitions of the 18.04 to the existing partitions of 17.10 but that's where I think I hit a snag.

First, a little bit about my setup - it was a dual-boot system spread over an SSD and an HDD. Only the documents were stored on the HDD (think downloads, pictures, basically the entire `/home` folder and it's Windows counterpart) - everything else was on the SSD.

Now, back to the problem - it looks to me like I created a second EFI partition by explicitly assigning the `/boot` location - which is how it used to be with 17.10, but it seems like it was installed in legacy mode. Here's what the `fdisk` used to say before the reinstall.

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FCA82D3C-D3F2-41F8-A17A-16500CC996B8

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 381069758 380502463 181.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 381071360 382722047   1650688   806M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 382724096 498069503 115345408    55G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 498069504 500117498   2047995  1000M Linux boot partition
```

Here's what it says now.

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FCA82D3C-D3F2-41F8-A17A-16500CC996B8

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 381069758 380502463 181.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 381071360 382722047   1650688   806M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 382724096 498069503 115345408    55G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 498069504 500117498   2047995  1000M EFI System
```

It looks like [this might be the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427266/how-to-create-efi-partition-and-install-grub2-on-second-disk) to my problem - to install the Linux EFI bootloader to the existing EFI system partition - but I wanted to double-check with the community if that's actually the issue. Thank you for any and all advice!

Answer (score 0):

Good news is I fixed it, bad news is I don't know what was the problem, which was the whole point of trying to fix it - please, please post another answer if you know something!

Here are the changes I made that made everything work.

1. Placed `/boot` on the first `EFI System` partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p1`).
2. Deleted the second `EFI System` partition because the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) strongly recommends to have only one EFI partition.
3. Ran `boot-repair` [utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) that reinstalled GRUB.
4. Disabled Secure Boot in BIOS.

All the changes were made from the live USB.